# How do I enable use of the Adobe Stencil font, "pslb"?

Tags: fonts, adobe

Using MiKTeX TeXWorks, I have the following line in a .tex file:
\font\test=pslb at 10pt
I get an error message, and after entering "h", I get the following message:

! Font \test=pslb at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
l.22 \font\test=pslb at 10pt

? h
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font='.

What can I do to fix this problem?
Thanks.

2024 MAR 01 MORE INFO:
In MiKTeX TeXWorks, I'm using pdftex. I have no problem loading/using certain fonts, e.g., pncb (new century bold) and phvb (helvetica bold).  But pslb does not work. I found these font names/codes in a file online with a list of font names/codes. I don't know why some work, and some do not. So I'm just trying to find out, by asking questions here, how to get all of the fonts in the list, in general, to work, but in particular I'm specifically interested in the bold stencil font pslb. Closer to the end of the long list there's pslr, which seems to be the "regular" (non-bold) stencil font. The list starts out as follows:

@c @mapfile{
@c   license = "public domain",
@c   email = "tex-fonts@tug.org",
@c   date = "19apr04",
@c   url = "http://tug.org/fontname/adobe.map",
@c   supported = "yes",
@c   docstring = "Adobe PostScript fonts."
@c }
@c
@c List of fonts sold or resold by Adobe Systems Inc.
@c
@c Font samples are available from:
@c
@c   http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/P/P_xxx.html
@c
@c This list of Adobe fonts is not limited to Adobe Originals.
@c It also includes fonts by other suppliers (Berthold, ITC,
@c Linotype, Monotype, etc.) which are resold through Adobe.
@c The original supplier is sometimes indicated by a prefix
@c or suffix of the font name.
@c

Comment: what sort of font is it? if it's type1 and you are using pdftex you will need to generate tfm metrics

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE

From your `MWE` understood that you are using either `LaTeX-dvips-ps2pdf` or `PDFLaTeX` to generate the output. For this, please refer https://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide?lang=en regarding how to install fonts

If you have the fonts in OTF format, then `autoinst` one of a fine tool for `OTF` to `type1` format.

Comment: The guide at the link is very helpful. I will take a few days (maybe more) to work on it. Thank you.